# How do I set Pycharm to start my project from a specific folder deep within my Git repository

Tags: python, pycharm, package, pythonpath

I am working on a Python project which is contained a few folders deep in my Git repo. e.g.

```
/home/userA/git_repo/product/utils/python_fwk/backend/my_project
```

Under this Git repo there are additional Python projects, belonging to other users.

When I start a new project and clone the Git repo, my project is set to start at `/home/userA/git_repo/...`, so now, when I import my packages into my code I need to:

```
from product.utils.python_fwk_backend.my_project.some_package.2nd_package import MyPackage
```

Since the python project is located under `.../my_project` I would like my imports to be as follows

```
from some_package.2nd_package import MyPackage
```

Comment: I thinnk you need to go in settings -> project structure

Comment: Thanks @gionni. That's what I eventually did. How can I also implement this outside Pycharm? Does this have to do with PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found is to add additional content paths to the project.

```
Pycharm -> File -> Settings -> Project: YOUR_PROJECT_NAME -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root
```

Now add the path that matches the project path

```
/home/userA/git_repo/product/utils/python_fwk/backend/my_project
```

This requires to remove the initial Content Root Path

```
/home/userA/git_repo/product/utils/python_fwk/backend/my_project
```

because there can't be overlapping of paths.

Now I can import using the shorter path

```
from some_package.2nd_package import MyPackage
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the ideal way. One problem is that this works within Pycharm. Now I have to make it from the CLI. This requires further checks by me. Would be happy to get better solutions.